# Xaml how to change the number of columns in same grid to display TextBlock

Tags: .net, xaml, datagrid, grid, silverlight-5.0

I am silverlight xaml and c# beginner. I have a nesting situation where i want to display a textblock with 1 column inside the text block with 2 columns in the grid. The view must be like this:

[image]

You can see that there is small algo for it:

```
Grid
{
  2 columns for first 3 TextBlock from row 0 to 2
  Only 1 column for the third row // I do so because here the data inside will be more(not able to cover in 1 line)
  Again 2 columns for third TextBlock 
 }
```

What i tried :

```
<Grid Width="300">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        <RowDefinition Height="" />
        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
        <RowDefinition Height="20" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Text="Name" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Name}" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Text="Author" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Author}" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Text="Date of Creation" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding DateCreation}" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Text="Company" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Company}" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Text="Description" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}" />

    <!--TextBlock  Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding Description}"/>-->

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="0" Text="DocUrl" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="6" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding DocUrl}" />

    <TextBlock Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="0" Text="ProgramId" />
    <TextBlock Grid.Row="7" Grid.Column="1" Text="{Binding ProgramId}" />

</Grid>
```

How to achieve it using Xaml ?

**Please not that i am working in silverlight 5**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set a property called Column span. This mean the element you are applying it to will "span" or be as wide as the number of columns you specify. Note you can also do this with grids as well. For you example, change the xaml code of your description label textblock and the bound description textbox to the following:

```
<TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="Description"/>
<TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Description}"/>
```

This should stretch those elements to the width of 2 columns. I hope this helps!

**Edit:** After further consideration I would Imagine you want the "Description:" text to still be included, but only in one box. To do this you'd have to use C# code behind as silverlight will only let a textbox bind to one thing. So instead I would only use:

```
 <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding DescriptionWithLabel}"/>
```

and in the C# that you are binding to :

```
public string DescriptionWithLabel
{
   return string.Format("{0} {1}", "Description: ", Description.ToString);

}
```

**Edit:**Ok, after your most recent comments I would suggest scrapping the DiscriptionWithLabel in the C# code behind and instead go with a stackpanel which contains a label and a textbox. Like so:

```
        <StackPanel Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,0,0,0" Grid.Row="4" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
            <TextBlock Content="Description: "/>
            <TextBox HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Width="auto" MinWidth="20" TextWrapping="Wrap" Max Width="60"/>
        </StackPanel>
```

Comment: it worked bu i have got a problem . What if i write a text which is even longer then the textblock size. It will be displayed incomplete string.

Comment: I am in short i wann grow the size of this text block dynamically according to the decription binding and the size should grow enough to accomodate to all the string . Suppose i take textbox instead of textblock because its more beautiful to have a box around the string written. So how to grow he size of this test box dunamically to accomodate all string ?

Comment: tHANKS FOR THE RECENT UPDATES. why not grid ? why stack panel ?

Comment: Error 1 The name "Label" does not exist in the namespace "http://schemas.microsoft.com/client/2007".

Comment: I am using silverligth 5

Comment: i TRIED THIS(eqvt to your code): <TextBlock Grid.Row="4" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="1" Text="Description"/>
                                        <TextBox Grid.Row="5" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Text="{Binding Description}"/> its the same output as your code : The output is stillcrossing the the border rather thn stretching the  row

Comment: I tried to use <Grid width="Auto" but it looks odd because It just keeps on increasing the width but i want to increase height keeping width constant  and the text must change the line as it exceeds the width (instead of crossing the border and etting disappear or increasing the width) ;because it looks odd that width increases just due to one text box .

Comment: I edited it for your new requests, but honestly. It sounds like you you look into taking a tutorial on xaml.

Comment: Big thanks. Yes i have switched to c# and xaml from c++. could you please suggest me some good links for xaml tutorial ? Would be good help.

Answer (score 2):

You have to set `ColumnSpan="2"`

```
<TextBlock Grid.ColumnSpan="2" ... />
```

Comment: @ Martin please explain a bit more . What it do ?

Comment: I meean how shoul i edit my Xaml code for having only 1 column in 3rd row ?

Comment: @user234839: you can set the `ColumnSpan` on any element in your `Grid` to say: this element shall cover so many columns. So set this ColumnSpan to all your elements in the 3rd row.

Comment: it worked but i have got a problem . What if i write a text which is even longer then the textblock size. It will be displayed incomplete string.I am in short i wann grow the size of this text block dynamically according to the decription binding and the size should grow enough to accomodate to all the string . Suppose i take textbox instead of textblock because its more beautiful to have a box around the string written. So how to grow he size of this test box dunamically to accomodate all string ?

Comment: @user234839 use TextWrapping Property of the Textbloxk to wrap, then the contents will be wrapped within the grid row.